# Find out which app is making notification sounds?

Tags: notifications, audio, samsung-galaxy-tab

I've got a Samsung Galaxy Tab 8, and a few days ago it started making a notification sound but with no notification banner. I don't know what app is doing it and I didn't install anything around the time it started.

Is there a way to trace this back to the source app somehow?

Answer (score -2):

You can disable your notifications by following these steps: (Depending on model of device and Android build these steps may or may not be exact)

1. Go to Settings -> Applications
2. Select Application and uncheck the 'Show notifications' box
3. When prompted to confirm -> click OK.

I did this manually, but there is an app in the Google Play store that can disable all notifications but it requires ROOT.

Here is the app in case you have ROOT access and decide to go that route: 
[Notifications Off](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.aboutmycode.NotificationsOff&hl=en)

Comment: I don't want to disable notifications. I'm getting a sound notification from one of my apps with no alert. I want to find out which app is making the sound!